# what is '-y' in RUN apk -update -y

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

What is '-y' in `RUN apk update -y`
Can I use the command without '-y'?

I am using `RUN apk update && apk upgrade` in my code.

Comment: I'm guessing ```-y``` flag is for ```yes to all``` (which I can't find in alpine apk man page), maybe author of the dockerfile mistake it for ```apt``` since ```-y``` flag for ```yes to all``` exists in apt

Comment: Depends on the base container image you use. Usually running commands in a build process implies non-interactive mode and the `-y` option should then not be mandatory. As stated by @Kristian, the `-y` forces `apk` to be "non-interactive" and will then not ask any question (all questions would be answered with "yes").

Comment: `RUN apk update && apk upgrade` is not efficient. The correct command is `RUN apk upgrade --no-cache`. See stackoverflow.com/a/76440791/685806

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

`RUN` Command is used when you use Dockerfile to execute a command inside the particular container.

#### what is '-y' in RUN apk -update -y

Well `-y`  as @kristian said is not found in `apk man page`, to be precise in alpine. Maybe it was `apt update -y` or `apk update` as `apt` comes in all Debian based flavors.

From the results of running `man apt-get`

```
-y, --yes, --assume-yes

           Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
           run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
           changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
           package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
           abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

#### Can I use the command without a `-y`

Yes!
If you run commands without the `-y` option, you need to answer to all prompts that you get from that command interactively in order for the execution of the command to continue.